# Swing and label setText doesn't work

Tags: java, swing

I need a little help with swing. This is my code:

```
public class UIdostawca extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    /** Creates new form UIdostawca */
    public UIdostawca() {
        initComponents();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    /* This is my function */
    public void loadStuff() {
        jLabel2.setText("Works or not?"); 
    }


    /*
      A lot of code generated by NETBEANS
     */


    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;

}
```

I use it like this:

```
UIdostawca a = new UIdostawca();

a.loadStuff();
```

and the jLabel2 didn't change ;(

However when in execute

```
jLabel2.setText("Works or not?");
```

in function like `formWindowOpened`

everything works

Comment: Hmmm sounds like you are resetting the `jLabel2` text somewhere after you call `a.loadStuff()`

Comment: Based on the random lines of code posted we can't be of much help. You need to post a proper [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @camickr i didn't want to paste all this auto-generaced code. I just wrote loadStuff method. And that's it what i changed in UIdostawca class.

Comment: Does your code work? We are not readers we can't guess what you may have changed. A SSCCE means you create a frame with a single JLabel added to the frame, then all the auto generated stuff is kept to a minimum. If you understand how to do this change, then you should be able to get it working in your real program. We don't want to see code with 100 different components added to the frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a multi-threading issue.  When `formWindowOpened` is called, it's called by the Swing event dispatch thread (EDT), which is the same thread that draws the interface, so it has the right value of text to draw.

If you call `setText` from some other thread, the EDT will probably not get the right value for the text.  Wherever you call `setText` in some other thread, you have to wrap it in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`, which whill change the text value on the EDT.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case did you initialize the jLabel2?

Comment: Could you post that code along with any other relievent code that happens between UIdostawca a = new UIdostawca(); and a.loadStuff();